# accessing host machine from a pod running on a kind cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I'm running a kind cluster and from one of the pods I need to access the host machine.  I know in minikube you can access it using `10.0.0.2` is there some way I can access it, the same way I could use `host.docker.internal` on Docker Desktop?

Comment: Are you not able to access it using hosts IP address?

Comment: I don't obviously see this option in the kind documentation.  Can you run whatever resource you need inside the cluster?  Or, if you don't need things like a multi-node cluster, use minikube instead?

Comment: did you figure this out ? did using 172.17.0.1 work ?

Comment: On MacOS using `172.17.0.1` did not work for me, but passing my local network address directly worked. You probably know you can find it using `ifconfig`

For instance, submitting this job to my cluster worked fine:

```ray job submit --address http://localhost:8265 -- python -c "import requests; requests.get('http://192.168.2.105:8000/data/coef.parquet')"```

Answer (score 3):

Docker uses default subdomain 172.17.0.0/16, and assign the pods IP address 172.17.X.X

Host server can be access using ip address 172.17.0.1

Comment: This is not necessarily true (the default network CIDR block is configurable and a `docker network create` network will have a different address), and this doesn't work on non-Linux hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Is it possible accessing host machine ports from Kind pods?](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1200)
, that most probably solution you are looking for.

1. [workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1200#issuecomment-568735188) using [qoomon/docker-host](https://github.com/qoomon/docker-host)

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dockerhost
  labels:
    k8s-app: dockerhost
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: dockerhost
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: dockerhost
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dockerhost
        image: qoomon/docker-host
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add: ["NET_ADMIN", "NET_RAW"]
        env:
        # Not needed in MacOs:
        - name: DOCKER_HOST
           value: 172.17.0.1 # <-- docker bridge network default gateway

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dockerhost
spec:
  clusterIP: None # <-- Headless service
  selector:
    k8s-app: dockerhost
```

2. check [iptables way](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1200#issuecomment-647145134)

> kind pod with a container name: test
>
> local container: myapp exposing port 8081
>
> Allow port in the firewall
>
> `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT`
> now from inside container test in kind cluster, you can run:

```
curl 172.17.0.1:8081
```

> where 172.17.0.1 is your docker bridge default gateway.

Comment: My default bridge for the kind network is 172.17.0.5, however when I try I actually sshed into the pod in question, and I tried a simple curl and ended up with the following error (curl 172.17.0.5:9200) <blockquote id="error"> <p><b>Access Denied.</b></p> </blockquote> <p>Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.</p> It does not even try to go out but simply gives an access denied error.